# Transform vs Translate in Raphael

Tags: raphael

I have seen in the raphael document that translate is depreciated and suggested to use transform instead. But my requirement is when i move an object i need the x, y or cx, cy need to updated to the server with latest value. This can be done easily using translate. But if i use transform it stores as `Tx,y`. How to get the modified x and y when using transform?

**example**

```
console.dir(page1);
var c1 = paper.circle(50,50,3);
c1.transform("T100,100");
```

here the cx and cy is still 50,50 but i need the value as 100,100

Comment: I think you need to calculate this yourself, the value is correct as its relative to your circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

transform() will change the coordinate system. If you only need to "move" a shape, then you can just change its position attribute that can be cx, cy, x, y depending on the shape. The following is a raphael extension that adds methods nt_translate() and nt_scale() to shapes and sets and also adds two custom attributes translateNT and scaleNT to shapes. So if you do aCircle.nt_translate(10,10) the circle's cx and cy attributes will change and it will be translated  without transform(). Hope that helps!